# installing gitorious in windows xp

Tags: git, gitorious

i want to install git server in windows xp.
i have looked for solutions like gitosis, gitweb, but their front end is not as good as github. gitorious looks good, but installation instructions are available only for linux.
**i need installation instructions for gitorius in windows xp.** i need to prove that git is better than CVS and SVN to my team.the only thing git lack is a standard server.

Comment: If you're working in a local network (VPN included) - you could easily use shared folders. It's easy to configure and use with git. We're working this way and haven't experienced any problems with it yet.

Comment: @ivan i am looking for a git server solution like github/gitorious to host it for my team, but in windows xp.

Comment: Oh, got it. Probably I will also tend to VM option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No guarantees but try installing it via Cygwin with consideration of: http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/setting_up_gitorious_on_your_own_server

Otherwise consider installing it onto a linux VM: http://groups.google.com/group/gitorious/browse_thread/thread/6507404e0d31117a

Based on previous experience I would prefer the second option, since there are too many components to be installed and it would be hard to predict all the possible hiccups if installed in cygwin.

Comment: i knew about the second option, but i am strictly looking for in windows xp.

Comment: yeah, my advice is to go with the second considering the complicated installation process of gitorious and obvious lack of windows support. If you are enterprising enough to try Cygwin, a vm would simply be more practical.